# The Dual Abelian Variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety defined over an algebraically closed field, say over $\mathbb{C}$. There is a dual abelian variety $\hat{A}$, along with a Poincare line bundle $L$ on $A\times \hat{A}$. Is there any relation between $\widehat {A\times A} $ and $\hat{A}\times \hat{A}$, for instance are they isogenous. What happens when $A$ is principally polarized, can we say relate the Poincare bundles in this case.

Comment: @Marty: You should write this as an answer.

Comment: Ok.. Done.  I've deleted my comments accordingly.

Answer (score 19):

You can define $\hat{A}$ as $\underline{\mathrm{Pic}}^0(A)$. Now, over any algebraically closed field $k$, let $V$ and $W$ be proper (irreducible, reduced) varieties. Then $\underline{\mathrm{Pic}}^0(V)\times \underline{\mathrm{Pic}}^0(W)\to\underline{\mathrm{Pic}}^0(V\times W)$ is an isomorphism. Injectivity is immediate, and surjectivity follows from the theorem of the cube (see e.g. Mumford, Abelian Varieties, section 6 in chapter II).

Answer (score 12):

Over any field $k$, $\hat A=Ext(A,G_m)$ in the abelian category (see ["Is the category of commutative group schemes abelian" here on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38168/is-the-category-of-commutative-group-schemes-abelian)) of commutative group schemes of finite type over $k$. There is a natural isomorphism $Ext(A \times A,G_m) \cong Ext(A,G_m) \oplus Ext(A,G_m)$ ($Ext$ is a bi-additive functor), from which a natural isomorphism $\widehat{A \times A} \rightarrow \hat A \times \hat A$ that you seek . The Poincare bundles on $(A \times A) \times (\hat A \times \hat A)$ and on $\widehat{A \times A} \times (A \times A)$ should be easy to relate as well -- just pullbacks via the canonical isomorphisms mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

Given two *complex tori* $X_1$ and $X_2$, there is always a canonical *isomorphism*

$\widehat{X_1 \times X_2} \cong \widehat{X}_1 \times \widehat{X}_2$,

see for instance Birkenhake-Lange's book *Complex Abelian Varieties*, Exercise 11 page 43.

Indeed let us write $X_i=V_i/\Gamma_i$, where $\Gamma_i$ is a lattice in the complex vector space $V_i$. Then

$X_1 \times X_2 \cong V_1 \times V_2/ \Gamma_1 \times \Gamma_2$

and, by standard representation theory of abelian groups, the character group of $\Gamma_1 \times \Gamma_2$ coincides with the direct product of the  character groups  of $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.