# The Picard group ao abelian varieties

Tags: abelian-varieties

Dear, my question is: If A and B are abelian varieties over an algebraically closed field, then Pic ^ {0} (A x B) = Pic ^ {0} (A) x Pic ^ {0} (B)?

Since already many thanks

Flavio.

Comment: Yes, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52267/the-dual-abelian-variety/52273

Answer (score 5):

In characteristic zero, yes. See [Picard group, Fundamental group, and deformation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57830/picard-group-fundamental-group-and-deformation/57839#57839) I don't know about characteristic $p$.